# How do webmasters migrate their site content when moving to a new platform?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, postgresql

I have a wordpress website with thousands of content submissions, I am now looking to scale the website and to do so would need to move it to a rails platform where I can implement more valuable features.

How would I go about somehow taking the wordpress database data and implementing it into a postgres/sqlite database format?

Any information/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no "correct" answer to this.  There are many different ways to approach it, and which you pick depends on a lot of factors that will be unique to your situation and that we don't know anything about

Comment: @Jason I know literally nothing about it at the moment, so I'm just looking for some direction at the moment to cover the subject briefly.

Answer (score 0):

**Wordpress Moving (new domain & new hosting):**

1. First **download your all files** from FTP.
2. **Export** your MYSQL database
   with phpMyAdmin or other platforms.
3. Open your sql database file with
   Notepad++ or other editors. Notepad++ is a recommented editor.
   Because it works very fast.
4. **Replace** all old domain with new domain in sql file. (**CTRL+H**)
5. **Import edited sql file** to your mysql of installed new Wordpress.
6. **Finally** enter *wp-admin > options >permalinks*, save with don't changing all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

1. Setup a new, clean Wordpress install at the destination
2. Copy over the /wp-content folder
3. Install WP Migrate on both environments
4. Use WP Migrate to push the content from QA to Prod for example